# get multiple occurance of a value after a specific word with regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

having a string similar to the following I would like to get the value **(test1, test2)** after the string `-option` (or wathever):

```
command --option test1 other stuff  --option test2  other stuff
```

I tried with as following

```
const regex = /--option ([^\w\s]) /g
regex.exec(string)
```

the problem is that I get just the first occurance and if there is more than 1 space it doesn't get the value

Comment: Try: `/-option\s+(\S+)/ig`

Comment: Side note, I'd suggest using a library like `yargs`, `minimist`, or `optimist` for managing the parsing of CLI options. Also, `--option` is the more _typical_ way to do long CLI options. That came from the GNU project's guidelines (https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Command_002dLine-Interfaces.html)

Comment: Slight change to @anubhava's suggestion: `/-option\s+(\S+)/g`

Comment: yeah actually i'm using --option not -option

Comment: btw both of them fix the problem of the "space" but they just take the first option

Comment: [
  '--option test1',
  'test1',
  index: 6,
  input: 'command --option test1  -option test2  stuff',
  groups: undefined
]

Comment: it should work with the global option but it doesn't

Comment: ok it works, thanks!

Comment: actually it works but it return this: [ '--option     test1', '--option test2' ] is there any to get the value? (i don't know if i can do .split because depends on the space

Comment: Does https://regex101.com/r/NfYgDQ/1 work as expected? The green parts are what you need to get, right?

Comment: yeah but I managed to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
/--option\s*(.*?)(?=\s*--option|$)/gi
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NfYgDQ/2). Details:

- `--option` - a literal string
- `\s*` - 0  or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\s*--option|$)` - immediately followed with 0+ whitespaces and `--option` or end of string.

See JavaScript demo:

```js
const str = 'command --option test1 other stuff  --option test2  other stuff';
const reg = /--option\s*(.*?)(?=\s*--option|$)/gi;
const results = [...str.matchAll(reg)];
console.log( Array.from(results, x => x[1]) );
```